# How to correctly close a socket and then reopen it?

Tags: java, sockets, client, socketexception

I'm developing a game for a class that I am in, and it is about 99% done. However, I realized there is a problem: If the server and client disconnect, and the client attempts to reconnect (and the server is back up and running fine), the client is not making a new connection.

The server and client are both multi-threaded. If I send the client a `Kick` message, what happens is the client will close its socket. If I reconnect, I get a `SocketException`: socket closed even though whenever connect is pressed, a new Client is constructed, which is basically just a class that creates a socket and connects to the server with a get/send thread.

Do you think there is anything I am doing illogically? It is like it is attempting to use the old Socket and Client that were constructed, but if I do some `println` calls, I can see that it does construct a new one and they are in different memory locations.

Thanks!

Comment: Check this question --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456607/can-i-close-and-reopen-a-socket

Comment: That didn't seem to help. I have realized that the new client is connecting because if I connect with a different name, the new name is realized on data sent. I forgot to mention that, for whatever reason, data is received fine. It's whenever I try to write to the outputstream when I get a socketclosed exception.

Answer (score 14):

After closing a socket, you cannot reuse it to share other data between Server and Client classes. From the [Java Socket API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html), about `close()` method's description:

> Any thread currently blocked in an I/O operation upon this socket will
>   throw a SocketException.
>
> Once a socket has been closed, it is not available for further
>   networking use (i.e. can't be reconnected or rebound). A new socket
>   needs to be created.
>
> Closing this socket will also close the socket's InputStream and
>   OutputStream.
>
> If this socket has an associated channel then the channel is closed
>   as well.

Then, **it isn't possible to close a socket and reopen it**. That's the reason, I think, of the exception being thrown.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am constructing a new Socket, and the weirdest thing is that after I construct the new one, if I write something to it's outputstream immediately after connecting, it writes it and I receive a response correctly. But if I call writeObject later, it gives the error!

Comment: @user1089097 Excuse me, I added my question after seeing your comment. It's really a strange problem. Maybe you close the Server socket before you write in the outputstream. Can you post some code in your question?

Comment: I have sorta figured out what the problem is. The chatbox is sending to the wrong client -- nothing is wrong in the client or server. I'm not sure how to fix that, because I construct the view with the client...but at least I know why. Thanks.

Comment: @user1089097 You are welcome. Now I'm glad you know why the problem is happening. If I understood well, you are developing a simple chat application. Some time ago, I written a simple program like yours and the socket managing is not easiest, but, with commitment, it's possible to solve the problems. If you are doubtful, you can ask here. ;-)

Comment: Now I'm even more confused. When The GUI is constructed, it is sent the Client. If I print out the clients name in the constructor, it is the new client's name. If I print it out in the command listener, it is the old clients name! This is why I can receive, but not send. I have no idea what could cause this, though!

Comment: I understood that the program still recognizes the new client as the old client disconnected before. But if I can't see some code, I will be more confused than you and I cannot help you properly!

Comment: I changed the markers of the Client to be Static and Volatile and now all is good. Thanks for being someone to bounce ideas off of.

Comment: Thanks, no problem. :-) I'm glad you solved and your application is working as expected.

Answer (score 4):

It can be easy! I made this program (server side):

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public class Host{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        while(true){
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1300);
            Socket s = ss.accept();
            DataInputStream din = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            String msgin = din.readUTF();
            System.out.println(msgin);
            ss.close();
            s.close();
            din.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Client side:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;

public class Client{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        while(true){
            Socket s = new Socket("localhost", 1300);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF("hello");
            s.close();
            dout.close();
        }
    }
}
```

It works, beacuse you can declare tons of Sockets with the same ServerSocket, so for example this works too:

```
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1300);
Socket a = ss.accept();
Socket b = ss.accept();
Socket c = ss.accept();
```

and you have 3 Sockets...
Remember: java waits for a client to connect when you declare a Socket!
Code:

Client:

```
import java.net.Socket;

public class client {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        Socket a = new Socket("localhost", 1300);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Socket b = new Socket("localhost", 1300);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        Socket c = new Socket("localhost", 1300);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        a.close();
        b.close();
        c.close();
    }
}
```

Server:

```
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class server {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1300);
        System.err.println("Listening...");
        Socket a = ss.accept();
        System.err.println("1");
        Socket b = ss.accept();
        System.err.println("2");
        Socket c = ss.accept();
        System.err.println("3");
    }
}
```