# C# detect TCP client disconnection

Tags: tcp

I am working on TCP multithread server with C# window application form, and I am trying to detect if the machine of client is shutdown and disconnects from the server. I have read some posts and have some ideas:

[How to determine if the tcp is connected or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993295/how-to-determine-if-the-tcp-is-connected-or-not)

[Instantly detect client disconnection from server socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)

But I'm not sure where to call the function `IsConnected`

My code is like the following:

```
public BindingList<Tablet> tabletList = new BindingList<Tablet>();
private Socket socket_Server = null;
    private Thread myThread = null;
    private Socket socket_Connect = null;
    private Dictionary<string, Socket> dic = new Dictionary<string, Socket> { };
    private string RemoteEndPoint;

socket_Server = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPAddress ServerIP = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.2.146");
        IPEndPoint point = new IPEndPoint(ServerIP, portNum);
        socket_Server.Bind(point);
        socket_Server.Listen(50);
        myThread = new Thread(Listen_Disp);
        myThread.IsBackground = true;
        myThread.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Server start");

private void Listen_Disp()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {

                //This is not working
                for (int i = 0; i < tabletList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (!SocketConnected(dic[tabletList[i].ip]))
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(RemoteEndPoint + "disconnected");
                    }
                }

                try
                {
                    socket_Connect = socket_Server.Accept();
                    RemoteEndPoint = socket_Connect.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(RemoteEndPoint + " is connected");
                    dic.Add(RemoteEndPoint, socket_Connect);

                    Tablet newTablet = new Tablet();
                    newTablet.ip = RemoteEndPoint;
                    newTablet.status = "Online";
                    tabletList.Add(newTablet);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine("end of while");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

static class SocketExtensions
{
    public static bool IsConnected(this Socket socket)
    {
        try
        {
            return !(socket.Poll(1, SelectMode.SelectRead) && socket.Available == 0);
        }
        catch (SocketException) { return false; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 4):

There's a lot of misinformation on that subject, and some of it is present in the questions you linked. The only reliable way to detect a TCP disconnection is to try to write to the connection. A read timeout can also indicate a dropped connection, but it may mean a lot of other things too, such as a stuck server. An EOS condition when reading indicates a graceful disconnect. The IsConnected() method and friends only give you a history of what you have done to this socket: they don't give you the current state of the connection. They can't, because, absent a pending write request, there is no state to
know. TCP doesn't maintain anything akin to a dial tone.

Comment: So what's the simplest way I can do if I just want to know my clients still alive or not? Keep receiving heartbeats?

Comment: Actually the real problem for me is that I dont know where to place the heartbeat codes

Comment: That's just a problem with how you organize your code. As you haven't posted any of it, it is impossible for anyone else to comment.