# Should I check TcpClient connect status with Poll or Writing zero bytes?

Tags: .net, networking, tcp, tcpclient

Is it the right way to detect TcpClient connection closed state, or do I have to write zero bytes? I know it may return true if the sockets is not closed gracefully at the other side. What I need is to detect closed sockets by Operating System.

```
static bool IsConnected(TcpClient tcpClient)
{
    if (tcpClient.Client.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectError))
        return false;

    if (!tcpClient.Client.Poll(10, SelectMode.SelectWrite))
        return false;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: @KlavsPeder No there was nothing about Socket.Poll. Also, I use keep-alive and I can see my connections are stuck in read but OS said they are in the closed state. I need a way to retrieve my socket status.

Comment: Do these questions solve your problem [C# How to determine if the tcp is connected or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993295/how-to-determine-if-the-tcp-is-connected-or-not)? and [C# Instantly detect client disconnection from server socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/722240/instantly-detect-client-disconnection-from-server-socket)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine if the tcp is connected or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6993295/how-to-determine-if-the-tcp-is-connected-or-not)

Comment: @richardec I had seen that before. They target different problem, also no one talk about SelectMode.SelectError