# React on client disconnect in linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, sockets

I am writing a simple socket daemon witch listens to a port and reads the incoming data. It works fine until i choose to disconnect a client from the server...then it enters in a infinte loop recv() returns the last packet never gets to -1. My question is how can i detect that the client had been disconnected and close the thread/ socket el

My thread is as follows :

```
void * SocketHandler(void* lp){
    int * csock = (int*)lp;
    int test = 0;

    char buffer[1024];
    int  buffer_len = 1024;
    int  bytecount,ierr;
    memset(buffer,0,buffer_len);
    while (test == 0)
    {
    if ((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){

        close(csock);
        free(csock);
        test++;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        syslog(LOG_NOTICE,"%s",buffer);

    }
    }
    return 0;
};
```

Comment: Are you using select() or epol()?

Comment: If you're using select, here is an answer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/283375/1158895

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A cleanly closed socket will end up in a `ZERO` read, while a broken connection is an error state returning `-1`. You need to catch the `0` return of your recv.

Comment: Not really, when you are just reading from it you can easily end up in a state where the systems still considers the socket open.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be I suspect you mean the "broken" state - this is ofcourse a property of TCP/IP. The "cleanly disconnected" state is guaranteed to return `0`on any sane OS

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the Linux implementation doesn't guarantee this even on clean disconnects, but yeah, when the stars are in the right position, you should get 0.

Comment: Well, the `0` is what is biting the OP ... on Linux.

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't notice the `== -1` :-D

Comment: It works thanks.Though it seems that is not a very professional solution it's the most handy!

Comment: @opc0de `man 2 recv` will tell you *"The return value will be 0 when the peer has  performed  an  orderly shutdown."*, so this **is** how it should work.

Comment: @EugenRieck `recv()` returning `-1` does not always indicate a broken connection. You must check `errno` for `EAGAIN`, `EINTR` and `EWOULDBLOCK` which are all recoverable errors.

Comment: @dwalter I never said it did - just the other way round: A broken connection (if the OS finds out it is broken - different story) will result in an error and thus a return value of `-1`.

Answer (score 0):

What happens here is that your end may not detect the fact the socket is dead (especially, if you are just reading from it).

What you can do is set keepalive on the socket. This will turn on periodic checks of the socket liveness. But don't expect fast reactions, the default timeout is something like 20 minutes.

```
i = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_KEEPALIVE, (char *)&i, sizeof(i));
```

Another option is to do your own keep-alive communication.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` will indicate a proper shutdown of the socket by returning `0` (see the [manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/2/recv) for details). It will return `-1` if and only if an error occurred. You should check `errno` for the exact error, since it may or may not indicate that the connection failed (`EINTR`, `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` [non-blocking sockets assumed] would both be recoverable errors).

Side note: there's no need to pass the `fd` of the socket as pointer and since you're returning a `void *` you may want to change `return 0` to `return NULL` (just for readability).