# Is there a way to monitor a specific program's internet connections and act if a break is detected?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, sockets

Specifically for the VoIP Software *Mumble*.

I have a fairly choppy connection to my frequented server and when it breaks I'd like to update a data file with various statistics at the time. I have all the code worked out for the statistics gathering, however I am not sure how to have this code trigger when the connection itself breaks. I've given **psutil** a go but could not find any connections from **Mumble** listed under the output.

Is there any kind of Python library that would allow me to monitor a programs active connection to a server and take action when it detects it has been broken?

Comment: You could check for the `http` status. Maybe something like `ping`

Comment: If you are simply looking for a library, this question is off-topic.  If you are trying to program a solution, you will need to provide more details.  As an example, what OS are you using.  Also, why is this tagged python 2 and 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ - Detecting TCP Client Disconnect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283375/detecting-tcp-client-disconnect)

Comment: Its common for voip to use UDP, not TCP and that would make it more difficult to detect. I don't know what mumble uses, but it would be worth a peek. You could monitor the network interface itself... `udevmon monitor` gives you running status of what's going on.